# Adding Alarms to execute code

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

My fairly new skill of coding isn't the best and on top of that I am working in a Android Development Kit. I have about 2 months of java under my belt but still need much help

How can I add two alarms to execute my code at a certain time? (Planning on making the execution time customizable so the users can choose the time)

Here is the two codes I want to executes at the desired times: (This Code Mutes the Phone)

```
mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

            int lowVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_RING);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, lowVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Phone Muted";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();


        }
    }
```

and this code (Unmute the Phone):

```
unmute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int topVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, topVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Phone Unmuted";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
        }
    }
```

How can I add two alarms that execute those two blocks of code and customization times? Don't have to answer both questions. Mainly - How can I add two alarms that execute code?

Comment: This is way too braod. Where are you stuck?? You might want [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: codeMagic, I editied the post.

Comment: It is not any more specific than before. Have you searched the issue at all to try and solve it?